# Why outputs' spendable and solvable are false?

Tags: transactions, wallet

I noticed a transaction whose spendable and solvable are both false, what does this mean and why?

```
 {
    "txid": "c940241a0ef626e865e2004bc120536fb7868d510115e923c76d5e658a97f6d5",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "mnbFFLXUqTPBweLm6w1GA2ZAJQbrTndEGC",
    "account": "",
    "scriptPubKey": "76a9144d98b2350032c849ac6e6e7ad0eb88e00fd7fbff88ac",
    "amount": 1.10000000,
    "confirmations": 132,
    "spendable": false,
    "solvable": false
},
```

Is this means this utxo is invalid somehow so cannot spend it?

Also, this is on testnet.

Comment: Could you tell us how you produced this output? That doesn't look like a transaction to me, but rather like a transaction output with some added data.

Comment: sorry my bad word, i meant utxo, not entire transaction. I used `bitcoin-cli.exe -conf="${pwd}\bitcoin-testnet.conf" -testnet listunspent` to list outputs in my local testnet node.

Comment: i do not see anything strange with it. you can spend it with a private key of mnbFF...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`listunspent`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listunspent) rpc call returns all unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs) tracked by this wallet. This includes the UTXOs that can be spent by this wallet, but also UTXOs that belong to watch-only addresses tracked by this wallet.

When `spendable` is false, this wallet does not have the private key to spend the UTXO. This is e.g. the case for watch-only addresses.

When `solvable` is false, the wallet does not know how to spend the UTXO, regardless of whether it has the corresponding private keys. It follows that any output that is `solvable` false will also be `spendable` false.

Comment: Spendable being false is implied by solvable being false. So perhaps he does have the private key, but not the necessary redeemscript?

Comment: Is there possible the case that spendable is true and solvable is false? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: "It is not possible for a script to be spendable but not solvable" - achow101 bitcoin PR review club March 9 2022 https://bitcoincore.reviews/19602

Comment: why wouldn't the wallet know how to spend an utxo?