# Bitcoin core -trying to open my watch adress with private key- unsolvable

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key-import, watch-only

First of all, please bare with my ignorance. When i bought btc 5 years ago i did not know more than i know today, which is very very little.

However, after retrieving my private key for an crashed hdd, i then created a new wallet in bitcoin core, i downloaded the whole blockchain, wrote -impprivkey in console followed by the private key connected to my old adress, where me btc had been resting for 5 years.

However, after a long scan it shows up in my wallet as unspendable. It shows only as a watch-wallet. Ok, i then write listunspent in console.
I get that the coins are
Spendable - false
Solvable - false
Safe- true

Now what can i do? What may have happened? I do have the private key. I have tried to sweep the coins into an electrum wallet, but since they are unspendable - aint gonna happen.

Any suggestions, anyone?

Thx and have a great day!

Edit:   I am looking at this as a lost case. But however it would be interesting to know what went wrong. Because when i did impprivkey in bitcoin core and waited the numerous hours for the rescan, the bitcoin did show up, but in the form of a watch adress and unspendable. The fact that -listunspent gave me : solvable - false,
Im curious to understand in what was it is unsolvable and why.

Thx again for any answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why outputs' spendable and solvable are false?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63198/why-outputs-spendable-and-solvable-are-false)

Comment: What happens when you attempt to import or sweep your private key to electrum? Electrum imports the key and then it says it is unspendable?